# Regular expression string matching any number of trailing characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector in which each entry looks like this:

```
"ABC1:123_CDE/CDE"
```

I would like to write a regular expression that matches ALL and ONLY characters trailing "_" so that I would get:

```
ABC1:123
```

I tried `"^_$|[CDE/]"` but that seems to select the initial C as well.

I read somewhere that lookbehind can be used in R if you set `perl = TRUE`, but I'm not super familiar with Perl regular expression matching either.

Many thanks, and apologies if there is something obvious I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

You can use a split method without regex since you are looking for a literal character:

(Perl)

```
my @res = split('_', $str, 2);
print $res[0];
```

(R language)

```
strsplit("ABC1:123_CDE/CDE", "_", TRUE)[[1]][1]
```

Comment: OP is using R, not Perl. (It's just Perl-compatible regexes)

Comment: The strsplit command worked in R. Does [[1]][1] tell R to consider only the first half of the string? If I use [[1]][2] it seem to take only take the second part of the string

Comment: @user3245575: When you split a string you obtain an array of strings. `[1]` is for the first item of the array, `[2]` for the second, ... With the string `A_B_C_D` `[3]` will return `C` and `[4]` `D`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("_.*", "", "ABC1:123_CDE/CDE")
#[1] "ABC1:123"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Could you explain to me step by step what each character is doing?

Comment: @user3245575 not much going on - it just matches the underscore and then anything after. I suggest reading up on [regex in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) if that's still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Match anything before a `_`

```
.*(?=_)
```

Comment: Won't work with a string of the form `ABC_DEF_GHI`. You'd rather want `.*?(?=_)` if you use that regex format.

Comment: Doesnt that depend on whether you want all characters before the first or last occurence of '_'?