# Regular expression to remove HTML line breaks at end of string

Tags: html, regex, line-breaks, trailing

I'm trying to remove all trailing HTML line breaks from a string., e.g. `<br>` or `<br/>` etc.

So this:

```
<br /> remove HTML breaks after this string    <br/><br><br /><br/><br><br /><br  /><br/>
```

Must become this:

```
<br /> remove HTML breaks after this string
```

I checked here:

- [Regular expression string matching any number of trailing characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412478/regular-expression-string-matching-any-number-of-trailing-characters-in-r)
- [Remove set of characters if they are trailing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009542/remove-set-of-characters-if-they-are-trailing-characters)

What I have so far `([<br\/>|<br>|<br \/>])?`, but that matches all line breaks including spaces

Test it live: https://regex101.com/r/XuWYqx/1

Comment: Would this pattern work ? `(<br \/>[\w ]+)<br\/>` https://regex101.com/r/bvjVlq/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match all trailing `br` tags:

```sh
\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>)+\s*$
```

Replace it with an empty string.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XuWYqx/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:<br\s*\/?>)+`: Match `<br` followed 0 or more whitespace followed by an optional `/` and closing `>`. Repeat this match 1 or more times
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `$`: End of line

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
/(<br \/> [\d\D]+)\s+<br/gmU
```

it puts everything up until the first <br in Group one.